# Another tricky preg_match

Tags: php, regex, text, preg-match

Just need to see if a paragraph contains a "stop word", the stop words are in an array below.

I had the formula as:

```
$pattern_array = array("preheat", "minutes", "stir", "heat", "put", "beat", "bowl", "pan");

    foreach ($pattern_array as $pattern) {
      if (preg_match('/'.$pattern.')/i', $paragraph)) {
        $stopwords = 1;
      }
    }
```

Which works well enough but for short words like 'pan' a word like 'panko' is identified as a stop word.

So the regex would be something like it has to have a space before it or be the start of a new line and either end in a full stop/space/comma/(other non character objects).

Also how could I tell php to exit the loop as soon as a stop word is identified?

**Thanks guys, slowing learning regex as I go!**

Comment: As far as stopping the loop when you find a match, check out php.net/break

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `\b(preheat|minutes|stir|heat|put|bowl|pan)\b` as your regex. That way, you only need one regex (no looping necessary), and by using the `\b` word boundary assertions, you make sure that only entire words match.

Comment: Ok Ive used that approach (the all in one regex not the \b) and I was warned about performance problems if the amount of items in the regex becomes too large. How many items would be too many?

Comment: Hard to say. I guess you're stuck with regexes if you want to match word boundaries, and looping over a multitude of regexes is probably slower than having one large regex. You could do some optimizations like `\b(p(?:reheat|ut|an)|st(?:ir|ove)|etc.)\b` so the regex engine can skip a partial match after finding that the first character(s) don't match, but better try it first before optimizing unnecessarily.

Comment: Hmm thats an interesting approach, its definitely a case of getting an app working as expected and then optimizing the little segments of stuff. Ill give that a try later and for your follow up ill accept your answer. cheers tim.

Answer (score 2):

Haven't tried this, but `\b` should be the character group you're looking for. From the  [PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.backslash.php):

```
 \b   word boundary
```

Your code would then look something like this:

```
$pattern_array = array("preheat", "minutes", "stir", "heat", "put", "beat", "bowl", "pan");

foreach ($pattern_array as $pattern) {
  if (preg_match('/\b'.$pattern.'\b/i', $paragraph)) { // also removed the ')'
    $stopwords = 1;
    break; // to exit the loop
  }
}
```

Edit: seems people are better off using \b, so changed this accordingly

Comment: it won't match at the end of the subject string.

Comment: or the beginning for that matter

Answer (score 2):

you need to add `\b` (which stands for word boundary) to your regex like this:

```
'/\b'.$pattern.'\b/i'
```

You seem to have a typo in your code, because either you have a literal closing bracket (and don't match parts of the words) or you have an open closing bracket.

Answer (score 2):

**1.** You can use "\b" to check for word boundaries.  A word boundary is defined as the boundary between a word character and a non-word character.  word-characters are letters, numbers, and underscore.

**2.** You can do it all at one go, by using "|":

```
$stopwords = preg_match('/\\b(preheat|minutes|stir|heat|..other words..|pan)\\b/i', $paragraph)
```

Comment: Ok Ive used that approach (the all in one regex not the \b) and I was warned about performance problems if the amount of items in the regex becomes too large. How many items would be too many?